# Swift 3 Alamofire JSON response

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have gotten to the stage where I get a response and am able to print the data into the console in Xcode but I cannot figure out how to sort the data. For example I have 4 types that are sent back to the client, and I want to be able to set them as variables to use in labels or other elements.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, encoding:     JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
        }
```

Comment: print(response.result)    print this for your result sent back to client

Answer (score 0):

You should really google this. You can find similar questions that have been asked multiple times.

Heres is an example

```
        var name : String?
        var age : Int?
        var stupid : Bool?
        var ageString : String?


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, encoding:     JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
               if response != nil {
                  name = response.name
                  age = response.age
                  stupid = response.stupid

               }
            }
//    If you want a response to be converted and stored, you can do this

             ageString = String(response.age)

//    To use this value on a label 
           nameLabel.text = name
           ageLabel.text = ageString
```